# Is there a singularity theorem in higher-dimensional Newtonian gravity?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations

In classical Newtonian gravity with 3 spatial dimensions, it's hard to get two particles to exactly collide, since at short distance the centrifugal force (~1/$r^3$) beats the gravitational attraction (~$1/r^2$). As a consequence, two particles can collide only if the angular momentum is exactly zero, which is measure zero.

In Newtonian gravity with $d$ spatial dimensions, the centrifugal force still goes like ~$1/r^3$ but the gravitational attraction goes like ~$1/r^{d-1}$. This means that for $d>4$, if two particles have negative total energy, they will collide regardless of their angular momentum. For two particles, having negative total energy is a sufficient condition to guarantee a collision after finite time.

My question is whether this is still true with more than two particles?

Conjecture: in $d>4$-dimensional Newtonian gravity, a collection of any number of point particles with negative total energy will experience a "singularity" (a distance=0 collision of at least two particles) within a finite time.

Comment: You can also get noncollision singularities: Z. Xia, “The Existence of Noncollision Singularities in Newtonian Systems,” Annals Math. 135, 411-468, 1992. https://plus.maths.org/content/outer-space-twos-company-threes-crowd http://www.ams.org/notices/199505/saari-2.pdf The electromagnetic version of your problem is basically open, in the sense that nobody has even found a compelling and precise way to define the problem. This is because radiation from pointlike charges is problematic to handle consistently in classical electromagnetism.

Comment: Note, however, that the Lagrange-Jacobi equation mentioned in the introduction to Xia's paper is basically the identity that is mentioned in my answer below: in particular, while in $d = 3$ it is possible for both the gravitational potential energy and $\sum |x_i|^2$ to run-off to infinity in finite time, this cannot happen in higher dimensions. @BenCrowell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should follow from the following [Virial-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) computation.

For convenience we assume all particles have the same mass; this is not essential.

Let $x_i$ denote the position vector of the $i$th particle, then Newton's law of universal gravitation, suitably normalized, gives

$$ \ddot{x_i} = (d-2) \sum_{j \neq i} \frac{ x_j - x_i}{|x_j - x_i|^d } $$

This gives

$$ x_i \cdot \ddot{x_i} = (d-2) \sum_{j \neq i} \frac{ x_j \cdot x_i - |x_i|^2 }{|x_j - x_i|^d} $$

summing over all particles we get

$$ \sum_{i} x_i \cdot \ddot{x_i} = (d-2) \sum_{i,j, i\neq j} \frac{ x_j \cdot x_i - |x_i|^2 }{|x_j - x_i|^d} =  -\frac{d-2}{2} \sum_{i,j, i\neq j}  |x_i - x_j|^{2-d} \tag{1}$$

Conservation of energy, on the other hand, states that

$$ - \sum_{i,j, i\neq j} |x_i - x_j|^{2-d} + \sum_i |\dot{x_i}|^2 = C < 0 \tag{2}$$

(by negative energy assumption). Summing (1) and (2) and using that $d \geq 4$ so that $(d-2)/2 \geq 1$ we get

$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \sum_{i} |x_i|^2 < 0 $$

Which shows that $\sum |x_i|^2$ must impact $0$ at some finite time (either future or past).

(Note: by "dropping particles at infinity" and using time-symmetric property of Newtonian mechanics we see that there exists trajectory where there is only one time of impact in the past, and none in the future.)

Comment: Incidentally, basically the same argument also works for the [Hartree equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_equation) for a quantum particle interacting with itself through a spherically symmetric potential. See for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02701 and references therein.

Comment: Why does the inequality after (2) imply that a collision will occur at the origin  in finite time?  Don't you need something like $d/dt \sum_i |x_i|^2 < 0$?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee: a strictly concave function that is positive at one point must equal zero somewhere. Something like $d/dt \sum |x_i|^2$ can NEVER be true in any time-reversible dynamical system.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee: to be more precise: We know by definition $R(t) := \sum |x_i|^2 \geq 0$. If $R(0) = 0$, we are done. If $R(0) > 0$, then look at $R'(0)$. If $R'(0) > 0$, by convexity for some $t < 0$ $R(t) = 0$. Vice versa for $R'(0) < 0$. If $R'(0) = 0$ then strict convexity implies that there exists both $t_+ > 0$ and $t_0 < 0$ where $R(t_+) = R(t_-) = 0$. Of course, $x_i = x_j$ for some $i\neq j$ may happen before the predicted singular times from looking at $R(t)$, but we know that if the dynamics is regular until $t_{\pm}$, at $t_{\pm}$ we must have all $x_i = 0$ and collision.

Comment: That's interesting.

Comment: Nice! One thing that confuses me is that on the face of it you have proved too much. I was expecting that *two* of the particles must collide, but you have apparently shown that they must *all* collide. Furthermore, according to your formula the collision must happen at the origin, even though that's just an arbitrary place. Is this because what really happens is that you get some two-point collision somewhere, and then the assumptions of proof break down?

Comment: @WillieWong typo: the $d-2$s in the exponents of Eqs. 1 and 2 should be $2-d$s.

Comment: @AdamB: thanks. Typo fixed. // In regards to your comment, I tried to address it in one of above comments, but I guess it didn't come through clearly. The point is that the breakdown will happen whenever the total gravitational potential energy becomes infinite. This can certainly happen _before_ $\sum |x_i|^2 \searrow 0$. What the argument shows however, is that $\sum |x_i|^2$ always remain bounded (so that the "escape" scenario that can happen for $n$-body 3D gravity cannot happen), and that some collision must happen (because as long as the collision doesn't happen, all the computations...

Comment: ... remain valid, which then implies that all particles must collide at the end). You should think that the proof shows that "collision must happen" by contradiction, but is a bit sharper than a pure contradiction argument because we also get an upper bound on the maximum possible time before collision (we get the bound from the energy). This is a standard technique for showing blow-up of evolution equations (both ordinary and partial differential eqs/systems); an example of its use in PDEs is [my recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06846v1).

Comment: Two comments above it should read, instead of $\sum |x_i|^2$ always remaining bounded, that $\sum|x_i|^2$ always remaining "bounded by a linear function of $t$".

Answer (score 3):

Following the lines  Willie followed,   but allowing for unequal  masses $m_i$, set $I(x) = \langle x, x \rangle $ where $\langle v, w \rangle = \Sigma m_i v_i \cdot w_i$ is the so-called mass metric built so that the kinetic energy is $K =\frac{1}{2}\langle v, v \rangle$ with $v = \dot x$. Here $x$ and $v$ lie in N copies of a d-dimensional Euclidean space.  Then Newton's equations read $\ddot x = - \nabla V (x)$ where the gradient $\nabla$ is with respect to the mass metric.  Suppose now that the potential $V$ is homogeneous of degree $-\alpha$. Using  Euler's identity $-\alpha V (x) = \langle x, \nabla V (x) \rangle$   a fun  elementary computation yields the  virial identity  $\ddot I = 4H +(2 \alpha - 4) V$, where $H = K +V$ is the total energy, which is conserved.  (This identity is called by mathematical celestial mechanicians the  Lagrange-Jacobi identity.)   Now for  $d$-dimensional ``Newtonian' gravity we have  $V < 0$ and $\alpha = d-2$ so that Lagrange-Jacobi reads $\ddot I = 4H +(8-4d)U$, with $U = -V > 0$.  Conclusion: for $d > 4$ and $H \le 0$ we have $\ddot I < 0$ and thus all such solutions either begin and end in total collision $I =0$,
(or have singularities before these total collision times),   as you conjectured.  (Asides.  If $d< 4$  then the virial identity implies  that $\ddot I > 0$ for $H \ge 0$ and consequently bounded solutions  have  $H < 0$. The case  $d =4$ is a wonderful bounding case between these  extremes. At the critical dimension $4$ solutions must lie on  spheres $I = const.$ and have energy  $H =0$  in order to be bounded.)